# Pull Numeric Value from XML String

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML string that is inputted into a MySQL column. If the result is success, the cell looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<success>
   <jobNumber>8038281923</jobNumber>
</success>
```

If it is a failure, it varies, but the cell looks roughly like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<failure>
   <message>blah blah</message>
</failure>
```

I am trying to write an `UPDATE` query that when it is a success, the `jobNumber` value is extracted from the XML string and written into the adjoining cell of the column `job_num`. If there is no `jobNumber` (such as in a failure), `job_num` is set to `0`.

Comment: So you [looked at the manual about XML functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html) and have a more specific question, right?

Comment: I understand that there is a general function ExtractValue()... I'm just not sure how the syntax of how to apply it, in this case...

Comment: You may need to take a wild stab at it to show you've tried something. A little demonstrated effort goes a long way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured how to use the function as part of a nested `SELECT`, so now I don't have to store the value in the table just to do `WHERE jobNumber IN`:

```
SELECT x.jobNumber, l.* FROM
(
SELECT lead_id, ExtractValue(xml_response, '//jobNumber') as jobNumber
from xml_table
WHERE status = 1
) x

JOIN leads l on x.lead_id = l.lead_id 

WHERE jobNumber IN (87242345,87441456)
```

Thanks to all for your assistance.

Comment: Note that this will not perform as well as the extracted-value column.  Also, the use of `ExtractValue` doesn't have anything to do with the join.  Kudos for solving your own problem!

Comment: You are correct. It is not the `JOIN` that was the issue. It was `WHERE jobNumber IN`. I have modified my post.